# C# compose connectionString in app.config using appSettings parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, app-config, appsettings

Is it possible to compose some xml entry in `app.config` (in my case some of `connectionStrings`) using `appSettings` parameters from the same file? 
Example:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContextDB" connectionString="Data Source =.;Initial Catalog = EFMyContextDB;Integrated Security = false;User Id=user;Password=pwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="UserId" value="userValue" />
    <add key="Password" value="pwdValue" />
  </appSettings>
```

I want to somehow use `UserId` instead of `user` and `Password` instead of `pwd` values of `MyContextDB's connectionString`.

This connection is then used in `DbContext` object:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("name = MyContextDB") { }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can look at using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`. Pass your existing connection string in to the constructor. Set the `Password` and the `UserID` properties. Then call `ToString()`.

You won't be able to pass the connection string like that for your `DbContext`. You could consider refactoring that to a factory pattern or something similar.

I would also consider using config transforms to actually update the config files at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder:

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContextDB"].ToString());

    builder.UserID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"];
    builder.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
```

Then, to get the new connectionstring:

```
builder.ToString();
```

Comment: isn't this what i said?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your comment.